# How to add average of specific column in time series data to that row in R?

Tags: r

I have data about the population of every state over time. For each row in this dataframe, I want to add an `avg_pop` column that is the average population of that state over all time periods. How can I achieve that in R?

Example:

```
st1 10
st1 20
```

should become

```
st1 10 15
st1 10 15
```

Because the average across st1 is 15.

I tried this but it does not work because the size of the dataframes is different:

```
averages = aggregate(data, list(data$state_name), mean, na.rm=T)
data$avg_pop = subset(averages, state_name==data$state_name)$stpop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to create a column, use `ave`

```
data$avg_pop <- with(data, ave(col_name, state_name))
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate a new column, you can use the `mutate` function:

`library(tidyverse)`

`df %>% mutate(avg_pop = mean(mass, na.rm = TRUE))`